# Working with regex and parentheses to return 3 groups: operand1/operator/operand2

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a Regex in JavaScript which matches a string and returns 3 groups: operand1,  operator, and operand2. For example dissecting an exponent clause:

```
const EXPONENT_REGEX = /(\S+)\s*([\^])\s*(\S+)/
const inpStr = '5 ^ 2 + 10 * 2'
inpStr.match(EXPONENT_REGEX) 
// Returns: ['5 ^ 2', '5', '^', '2'] 
// i.e. [Matched Clause, Operand1, Operator, Operand2]
```

When trying a similar approach to handle parentheses clauses however, and possible nested parentheses- I've been unable to find the right arrangement of escape square brackets and parentheses for grouping to return me those 3 values. Consider:

```
const PARENTHESES_REGEX = /\([^\(\)]*\)/
const inpStr = '5 ^ 2 + 10 * (10 - (4 + (2 + 1))'
inpStr.match(PARENTHESES_REGEX)
```

Currently this does not return any groups, but does match '(2 + 1)'. How might I structure this to return those same 3 groups as the first example? Here that would look like:

['2 + 1', '2', '+', '1']

Comment: /(\d{1,}) (\^|\*|\/|\+|\-|\~) (\d{1,})/g could be a start; fire it up over at https://regexr.com/

Comment: @BGPHiJACK Heya, thanks for the reply. I tried it at regexr and regex101- but both times was given an error, regex101 highlighted the * and gave an error of: 'The preceding token is not quantifiable'. I'm experimenting with it now though to see if I can incorporate it- from what I see it doesn't target the innermost parentheses though?

Comment: ... it's missing a backslash before the "*".

Comment: That's because you copied the /.../g into the expression area, just copy between those points and set the flags how you want g = global, i = case insensitive, m = multi line. expression: (\d{1,}) (\^|*|\/|\+|\-|\~) (\d{1,})

Comment: Ok, thank you both- got it up and working now! I'll try inserting it inside my original regex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const PARENTHESES_REGEX = /\((-?\d*\.?\d+)\s*([-+\/*])\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\)/g
const inpStr = '5 ^ 2 + 10 * (10 - (4 + (2 + 1))'
console.log([...inpStr.matchAll(PARENTHESES_REGEX)])
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-+\/*]                  any character of: '-', '+', '\/', '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

**Results**: `(4) ['(2 + 1)', '2', '+', '1', index: 24, input: '5 ^ 2 + 10 * (10 - (4 + (2 + 1))', groups: undefined]`